# Not supported In Simulator for jar file (CodeName One)

Tags: java, executable-jar, codenameone

I created an application that uses MediaRecorder, it creates a file in my application directory and records into it, it worked fine.
But later i decided to make a desktop version of it without sending it to the build server by following the instructions i found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/pro$20only$20feature/codenameone-discussions/iOsTe0sDZSs/oKq14mCWPdIJ)
My app is working fine, but i don't think it does the recording, infacts it throws a null pointer exception and the file path it shows when i try to show it with a dialog is something like this file://homeaudioSample1410359700375. Which makes me know that it seems to behaving like it is running in simulator. So i decided to run the jar from the command prompt and what i got was an error: not supported in simulator. What is the solution to this as i want the app to also run on non-mobile platform, or is there no other way around this except sending it to the build server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media recorder isn't supported in the JavaSE port of Codename One.

You can use a [native interface](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) implementation for JavaSE support. Media is just really problematic for desktop Java...

Comment: Already did that is there any other jar file i need to add to the java desktop application i created apart from javaSE.jar and the jar for the application. because my application is throwing an error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pushcv.interview.AudioRecordingInterfaceImpl`

Comment: Is this in the simulator or desktop build?
Which IDE are you using?

Comment: In the desktop build, i am using NetBeans, i was thinking there was no compiled version of the AudioRecordingInterfaceImpl.java, but i found it in the internal_tmp directory under the native directory.

Comment: Is that an old project that you created (3 months or so) or is this in a newly created project with a current version of the plugin?

Comment: the project is a new project, but a java project not a codename one project and i imported included the required jars. Do i need to import anything.

Comment: Did you use the desktop build with include source to generate that project? If not just paste the native code into your src directory.

Comment: thanks Shai, pasting the native code in the src directory worked but it won't clean and build with it in the src directory.

Comment: Its hard for me to understand what you did here. If you are a pro account (which you need to be to send a desktop build) you can just email support and I'll help you from there.

Comment: No probs, thank you so much, i needed to update the jar by adding my interfaceimpl.class, searched on how to do that and i have done it.